# Batch custom rename files with applescript

Tags: applescript, file-rename

I have hundreds of image files that are currently named:

[LASTname], [firstname].jpg

I need to rename them all:

[firstname]_[LASTname].jpg

So I can't do a simple search and replace or sequential convention or anything like that. I need to copy what comes after the comma, paste it to the front and replace the ", " with a "_"

I am very new to applescript, but it appears that might be a solution. Does any have any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a backup first, then do this on a spare COPY of your files in a separate directory.

Save this in your HOME directory as `go`

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

for f in *,*.jpg; do
   base=${f/.*/}      # strip extension
   last=${base/,*/}   # remove comma and anything after
   first=${base/*,/}  # remove anything up to and including comma
   echo mv "$f" "${first}_${last}.jpg"
done
```

Now start `Terminal` and make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x go
```

Now change directory to where your images are, so if they are in your Desktop in a folder called `COPY`

```
cd Desktop/COPY
```

Then run the script with:

```
$HOME/go
```

If the commands look correct, edit the script and remove the word `echo` near the end and run it again, for real.

By the way, `mv` is the command to rename a file, so the following changes `fileA`'s name to `fileB`:

```
mv fileA fileB
```

Comment: When I try that apple script I get a Syntax error that says "Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier."

Comment: Please try copying and pasting it again - I made a small change. It's actually a `bash` script rather than Applescript, btw.

Comment: That worked!!!!  Wow!  Thank you so much!  You have no idea how much time this will save me!

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with your project.